# How to Join two ObservableCollection into one ObservableCollection by using LINQ join Query in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, prism

I have two ObservableCollection named Customer and Group in Silverlight MVVM project that using Entity Framework.

I need to join this two ObservableCollection and need to yield a new ObservableCollection named Final. Joining is made up of using Conditions.

1st ObservableCollection had the following fields

```
cid, groupid uname
1    2       Raj
2    3       Jeya
```

2nd ObservableCollection had the following fields

```
groupid groupname
2     Traveler
3     Shopper
```

and my final table looks like the following

```
uname groupname
Raj    Traveler
Jeya    Shopper
```

Is there anyway to get it the final result..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply create an ObservableCollection from the join (as suggested in other answers), your collection will not be "observable." That is, changes to the original collections will not propagate. To propagate changes, you need to create a new collection class that implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

In the following code, I raise CollectionChanged with Reset action, which prompts the subscriber to re-load the entire result of the join. This is slower, but if you want specific per-item updates, you have to carefully tack the changes. This is much more complicated. Probably no use using LINQ in that case either.

```
public class Customer { public int cid; public int groupid; public string uname; }
public class Group { public int groupid; public string groupname; }
public class CustomerGroup { public string Name { get; set; } public string Groupname { get; set; } }

public class ObservableJoinOfCustomersGroups : IList<CustomerGroup>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    readonly ObservableCollection<Customer> customers;
    readonly ObservableCollection<Group> groups;

    List<CustomerGroup> cachedJoin; 

    public ObservableJoinOfCustomersGroups(ObservableCollection<Customer> customers, ObservableCollection<Group> groups)
    {
        this.customers = customers;
        this.groups = groups;

        cachedJoin = doJoin().ToList();

        customers.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            cachedJoin = doJoin().ToList();
            if( CollectionChanged != null )
                CollectionChanged.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        };
        groups.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            cachedJoin = doJoin().ToList();
            if( CollectionChanged != null )
                CollectionChanged.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        };
    }

    private IEnumerable<CustomerGroup> doJoin()
    {
        // Join code here
        return customers.Join(groups, p => p.groupid, g => g.groupid, (p, g) => new CustomerGroup{ Name= p.uname, Groupname = g.groupname });
    }

    public IEnumerator<CustomerGroup> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return cachedJoin.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(CustomerGroup item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(CustomerGroup item)
    {
        return cachedJoin.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(CustomerGroup[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(CustomerGroup item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public int Count { get { return cachedJoin.Count(); } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return true; } }
    public int IndexOf(CustomerGroup item)
    {
        return cachedJoin.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, CustomerGroup item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public CustomerGroup this[int index]
    {
        get { return cachedJoin[index]; }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly, but is this what you're looking for?

Create a new class named CustomerGroup:

```
public class CustomerGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Groupname { get; set; }
}
```

And create a matching ObserverableCollection:

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();

var result = new ObservableCollection<CustomerGroup>(
            customers.Select(
                x => new CustomerGroup{Name = x.uname, Groupname = groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.groupid == x.groupid).groupname}));
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create a new class :

```
  public class Result
```

{
    public string UserName{ get; set; }
    public string Groupname { get; set; }
}

and then create your query

```
 List<person> persons = new List<person>();
        List<group> groups = new List<group>();

        persons.Add(new person() { cid = 1, groupid = 2, uname = "Raj" });
        persons.Add(new person() { cid = 2, groupid = 3, uname = "Jeya" });

        groups.Add(new group() { groupid = 2, groupname = "Traveller" });
        groups.Add(new group() { groupid = 3, groupname = "Shopper" });

         ObservableCollection<Result> res= new ObservableCollection<Result>(
             persons.Join(groups, p => p.groupid, g => g.groupid, (p, g) => new Result{ UserName= p.uname, Groupname = g.groupname })
             );
```